# Remove CSS Modal Flash on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS modal on my page that is automatically hidden by JS until a Sign Up link is clicked. My problem is that when the page loads, the modal briefly flashes before being hidden.

I have used JS Hide function on the modal but am unsure of how to prevent the flash on page load, without disabling the ability for it to show on sign up click.

Modal HTML:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" id="close">X</a>
                <header><h2>Header</h2></header>
                <form><p>Form Contents</p></form>
            </div>
</div>
```

Hide (and reveal on click) JS:

```
<script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  // Hide Modal by default
              $('#openModal').hide();
                  // Show Modal on click of Signup
              $('#signup').click(function(){ 
                  $('#openModal').fadeIn(500);
              }); 
                  // Hide Modal on click of Close
              $('#close').click(function(){ 
                  $('#openModal').hide();
              }); 
          });
</script>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.
D

Comment: is using css too mainstream nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution would be adding `display: none` to your `.modalDialog` class. Then you won't have to hide it by default (`$('#openModal').hide();` line will not be necessary) and jQuery's `.show()` will override css.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea the JS would override the CSS, otherwise I would have managed to get to that by myself! Appreciate the knowledge and help.

Answer (score 1):

Style atribute:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" style="display: none;">
            <div>
                <a href="#close" id="close">X</a>
                <header><h2>Header</h2></header>
                <form><p>Form Contents</p></form>
            </div>
</div>
```

or:

```
var $ = typeof (jQuery) === 'function' ? jQuery : typeof ($) === 'function' ? $ : false;    
if ($ && $('#openModal').length) $('#openModal').hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //...                  
    });
```

Comment: how can you select a dom Element that may be not loaded already ? the goal of `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Hacketo If you include your js at the end of the page, after content, you can basically use jquery un document (not ready yet, but imported scope), http://jsfiddle.net/mhh5fsfp/  and http://jsfiddle.net/mhh5fsfp/, even your dom is not been loaded you can use jquery over partial dom loaded, not a good practice but...

Comment: I know, but use `$(document).ready` is useless so. As you don't know where is OP code located you can't advice using this way without specifying what you said in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Use css display:none to hide the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from this part of your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#openModal').hide();

});
```

This is waiting that all the html has loaded before firing your code, so hiding your modal.

JQuery `hide` function is adding an inline style to your element `display:none` so you could add this inline style yourself on the dom element to avoid this flash

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" id="close">X</a>
        <header><h2>Header</h2></header>
        <form><p>Form Contents</p></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hacketo. I've implemented this and it works perfectly. Bartek posted basically the same so as his answer was first I accepted that one. Appreciate your time.

Comment: make a complete answer takes more time :p, but as you want.